# How to prevent components from refreshing when state in context is changed (React)

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-context

Im shooting my shot at making a tiktok clone as a first project to learn React. I want to have a global isVideoMuted state. When you toggle it, it should mute or unmute all sound of all videos.

Except something is not working properly. I understand that react re-renders everything when you change one thing within the contextprovider parent component from a childcomponent. This resets the tiktok "scrollprogress" to zero, since its a simple vertical slider. Is there anyway I can prevent this from happening?

This is my VideoContextProvider:

```html
const VideoContextProvider = ({ children }: any) => {
  const [isVideoMuted, setIsVideoMuted] = useState(true);
  const [videos, setVideos] = useState([] as Video[]);

  return (
    <VideoContext.Provider
      value={{
        videos,
        setVideos,
        isVideoMuted,
        setIsVideoMuted,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </VideoContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

And this is the VideoCard.tsx (one single video):

```html
const VideoCard: FC<Props> = ({ video }) => {
  const router = useRouter();

  const [isLiked, setIsLiked] = useState(false);
  const [isVideoPlaying, setIsVideoPlaying] = useState(false);

  const { isVideoMuted, setIsVideoMuted } = useContext(VideoContext);
  
  return (
  
  .... (all the remaining videocode is here, including the <video>)
  
  
  <Box p="xs">
    {isVideoMuted ? (
      <VscMute
        fontSize="28px"
        color="white"
        onClick={() => setIsVideoMuted(false)}
      />
    ) : (
      <VscUnmute
        fontSize="28px"
        color="white"
        onClick={() => setIsVideoMuted(true)}
      />
    )}
  </Box>
  
  ...
  
    );
  };
  
  export default VideoCard;
  // export const VideoCardMemoized = memo(VideoCard);
  
  )
```

See this video for an example of the bug: https://streamable.com/8ljkhl

Thanks!

Edit:

**What I've tried so far:**

1. Making a memoized version of the VideoCard and using that, refreshing still occurs
2. Moving `const { isVideoMuted, setIsVideoMuted } = useContext(VideoContext);` to a seperate component (VideoSidebar). Problem still occurs, since I have to 'subscribe' to the isVideoMuted variable in the video element

Answer (score 1):

It rerenders only components that are subscribed to that context.

`const { isVideoMuted, setIsVideoMuted } = useContext(VideoContext);`

To prevent rerendering child components of the subscribed components you can use `React.memo`

`export default React.memo(/* your component */)`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response! I just edited my VideoCard.tsx component at the bottom where I make a memoized component like so: `export const VideoCardMemoized = memo(VideoCard);`.  I then import this component in my page (`import { VideoCardMemoized } from "../components/Video/VideoCard";`) and use it. Is this how I should do it? For me it doesn't make a difference, the error still occurs

Comment: You did not provide a lot of code. Are you using `useContext` at the action icon level (where the mute icon is)?

Comment: Yes, my excuses. I've edited my OP with the codesnippet of VideoCard.tsx for more clarification! I am using useContext in VideoCard.tsx where both the mute button (see codesnippet) and <video> element is.